# implementing HTTP method PATCH in python using bottle framework and pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, http, pymongo, bottle

I am trying to build a RESTful api using bottle. 
I am currently having trouble implementing HTTP method PATCH, so I hope someone can help me out finding what I am doing wrong.
I am pretty new to python, bottle, and mongodb, so this is more of a learning process.

Here is how db is set up

```
dbname = "movies"
#plugin = MongoPlugin(uri, db, json_mongo=True)
connection = MongoClient(uri, 27017)
db = connection[dbname]
db[dbname].insert(movies)
```

The data I put in the db

```
movies = [{'title' : 'Blade Runner', 'rel_date' : '25 June 1982', 'prod_company' : 'Warner Bros.'},
      {'title': 'Snatch', 'rel_date': '19 January 2001', 'prod_company': 'Columbia Pictures'},
      {'title': 'The Godfather', 'rel_date': '24 March 1972', 'prod_company': 'Paramount Pictures'},
      {"title": "Fight Club", "rel_date": "21 September 1999", "prod_company": "20th Century Fox" }]
```

And here is my method to handle PATCH

```
@app.route('/<name>', method='PATCH')
def update_movie(name):
    data = request.body.read_line()
    if not data:
        abort(404, 'No data received')
    entity = json.loads(data)
    db[dbname].update({'title' : name}, {'$set':entity}}) # edited
    return {'Message' : 'The movie was updated'}
```

I use Postman to send requests. If i send PATCH request like this

```
http://localhost:8080/test
passing: {"rel_date": "new_date"}
```

I get Error: 405 Method Not Allowed : the requested url caused an error.
Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly serving through an upstream proxy which does not have `PATCH` enabled? Seems to be [allowed by bottle itself](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.patch). Your update code is wrong though and would be `db[dbname].update({'title' : name}, {'$set': entity })` considering that `entity` would come out as a valid dict already and simply wanted to overwrite all paths present in the content that is.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for reply. So you are saying that the problem might be outside of code? Did I understand you correctly? Thanks for the code corrections.

Comment: That does seem to be a valid implication. If the documented API says the method is supported, then the only thing that can be reporting the error needs to be "upstream" of the implemented request handlers here. So if you're running behind an nginx or any other method of proxy, or indeed the WSGI container,  you probably should be looking there. Try testing with the essential "hello world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. My rout was not set up properly, which caused a 405.
Also corrected some errors inside the function.

```
@route('/movies/<name>', method='PATCH')
def update_movie(name):

    data = request.json
    if not data:
        abort(400, 'No data received')

    try:
        db[dbname].update_one({'title' : name}, {'$set': data})
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

    return {'Message' : 'The movie was updated'}
```